# Updating / Pushing Changes to a Views from Local to Staging Server?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I'm working on a complex view which is from an existing view that currently just needs a bunch of fields and exposed filters added. I have it working on my local desktop and now I want to make these same changes on the Staging/Dev server. How can I update the server without doing everything from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

If your working on an existing View and not a new one, you can just use the import View option on your server. Once you click into that page just check off the following:

**Replace an existing view if one exists with the same name**

It will update the existing view with what you have done on the local. On your local desktop just click on **export** on the view and copy and paste the code given to the server Views import page.